# CMake + Qt, moc compilation fails, cannot implement QMetaObject methods (compiler can't find header for base ui object?)

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt-creator, moc

I have a Qt 5.13, 64bit Windows project that I am porting from qmake to cmake. The project fails to compile the generated mocs_compilation.cpp file which includes objects generated from a couple of nested folders. It seems to compile through the generated moc_*.cpp files that are included, but bails on the 12th one with the following message:

> c:\users\marcus\projects\build-videosuite-desktop_x86_windows_msvc2017_pe_64bit-debug\video\libvideo_autogen\UVLADIE3JM/moc_ImageView.cpp(58): error C2653: 'ImageView': is not a class or namespace name
>   c:\users\marcus\projects\build-videosuite-desktop_x86_windows_msvc2017_pe_64bit-debug\video\libvideo_autogen\UVLADIE3JM/moc_ImageView.cpp(66): error C2653: 'ImageView': is not a class or namespace name
>   c:\users\marcus\projects\build-videosuite-desktop_x86_windows_msvc2017_pe_64bit-debug\video\libvideo_autogen\UVLADIE3JM/moc_ImageView.cpp(76): error C2653: 'ImageView': is not a class or namespace name
>   c:\users\marcus\projects\build-videosuite-desktop_x86_windows_msvc2017_pe_64bit-debug\video\libvideo_autogen\UVLADIE3JM/moc_ImageView.cpp(77): error C2270: 'metaObject': modifiers not allowed on nonmember functions
>   c:\users\marcus\projects\build-videosuite-desktop_x86_windows_msvc2017_pe_64bit-debug\video\libvideo_autogen\UVLADIE3JM/moc_ImageView.cpp(81): error C2653: 'ImageView': is not a class or namespace name

It was complied like this:

> C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~4\2017\PROFES~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1416~1.270\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe
>   /nologo /TP -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB
>   -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DUNICODE -DWIN64 -D_UNICODE -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -D_WINSOCKAPI_ -IVideoProcessor -IC:\Users\marcus\Projects\VideoProcessorSuite\VideoProcessor -IVideoProcessor\libVideoProcessor_autogen\include -IC:\Users\marcus\Projects\VideoProcessorSuite\VideoProcessor\opengl -IC:\Users\marcus\Projects\VideoProcessorSuite\VideoProcessor\src -IC:\Users\marcus\Projects\VideoProcessorSuite\VideoProcessor\algorithms
>   -IC:\Qt\Qt5.13.0\5.13.0\msvc2017_64\include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.13.0\5.13.0\msvc2017_64\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\Qt5.13.0\5.13.0\msvc2017_64\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\Qt5.13.0\5.13.0\msvc2017_64\include\QtANGLE -IC:\Qt\Qt5.13.0\5.13.0\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore -IC:\Qt\Qt5.13.0\5.13.0\msvc2017_64.\mkspecs\win32-msvc -IC:\Qt\Qt5.13.0\5.13.0\msvc2017_64\include\QtOpenGL -IC:\Qt\Qt5.13.0\5.13.0\msvc2017_64\include\QtNetwork -I"C:\Program Files\OpenCV 3.4.3\include" -I"C:\Program Files\OpenCV
>   3.4.3\include\opencv" /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 /showIncludes
>   /FoVideoProcessor\CMakeFiles\libVideoProcessor.dir\libVideoProcessor_autogen\mocs_compilation.cpp.obj
>   /FdVideoProcessor\CMakeFiles\libVideoProcessor.dir\libVideoProcessor.pdb
>   /FS -c VideoProcessor\libVideoProcessor_autogen\mocs_compilation.cpp

The source code has nested folders similar to this:

```
-Project/
 -CMakeLists.txt
 -src/
   -Widget.cpp, ImageView.cpp, MainWindow.cpp, etc.
 -opengl/
   - GlControl.cpp, etc.
 -logic/
   - Processor.cpp
```

The ImageView generated moc methods file that causes the error is the 12th in the mocs_compilation.cpp, so I'm assuming that the other included files are okay. ImageView is a generic widget.

```
#ifndef IMAGEVIEW_H
#define IMAGEVIEW_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QObject>

namespace Ui {
class ImageView;
}

class ImageView : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ImageView(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~ImageView();

    QImage getImage() {return m_image;}

    void setImage(QImage &image);

private:
    Ui::ImageView *ui;

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) override;

    QImage m_image;
};

#endif // IMAGEVIEW_H
```

My CMakeLists.txt file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(VideoProcessor)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Widgets Gui Test Network OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV COMPONENTS world REQUIRED)


set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

# for generated files to be read
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

# UIC needs to be able to look in nested folders
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC_SEARCH_PATHS src/ algorithms/ opengl/)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

file(GLOB OpenGL_Sources "opengl/*.cpp")
file(GLOB GUI_Sources "src/*.cpp")
file(GLOB Logic_Sources "logic/*.cpp")

# main.cpp is in src/ need to filter it out of the library target
list(FILTER GUI_Sources EXCLUDE REGEX ".*main.cpp$")

include_directories(opengl/)
include_directories(src/)
include_directories(logic/)

add_compile_definitions(_USE_MATH_DEFINES _WINSOCKAPI_ _UNICODE WIN64 UNICODE)

## Tests
#enable_testing()
#add_executable(testing tst_test.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(testing lib${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::OpenGL Qt5::Network ${OpenCV_LIBS})
#add_test(NAME testing COMMAND  testing)

add_library(lib${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenGL_Sources} ${GUI_Sources} ${Logic_Sources} "resources.qrc")
target_link_libraries (lib${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::OpenGL Qt5::Network ${OpenCV_LIBS})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}  "src/main.cpp")
target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} lib${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::OpenGL Qt5::Network ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

This project does compile using qmake. I have other nested folder Cmake/Qt/OpenCV projects similar to this that compile without a problem. What am I missing? The include flags used by the compiler include the directory that has the header file for ImageView. Why can't it find the class declaration? Is that even the real cause of this problem???

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have made a copypaste error and have two header files with `#define IMAGEVIEW_H`, would you?

Comment: That was it. Changed the macro name in header file and the problem went away.

Answer (score 2):

Changing:

```
#ifndef IMAGEVIEW_H
#define IMAGEVIEW_H
```

to

```
#ifndef MYIMAGEVIEW_H
#define MYIMAGEVIEW_H
```

fixed the problem.